# Magento 1.9 AOE_Profiler

Tags: magento-1.9, profiler

I've uploaded all the files from [aoe profiler git](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler) to my store root folder and then i've edited the `var/aoe_profiler.xml` to `<trigger>always</trigger>` but when i load my front page i don't see any profiling being made.

Clearly i'm missing something X_X. Can somebody please help me figure it out? Thanks! :D

P.S I have Magento 1.9.2.4 installed

Answer (score 0):

The url should have `?profile=1` after the address.

You should refer to link - http://fbrnc.net/blog/2014/11/how-to-install-a-magento-module

Comment: hey @LAW, now i've tried `https://example.com/index.php?profile=1` but i still see nothing at the bottom of the page (also changed the `aoe_profiler.xml` to ` <trigger>parameter</trigger><!-- 'always', 'parameter', or 'never' -->` :( what should i do now? :-s

Comment: Did you run the command $ modman deploy Aoe_Profiler ?

Comment: hmm, no, i just copied the files over :-s, how do i run that comand? X_X

Comment: P.S: i'm using ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and i connect trough ssh using Putty

Comment: http://fbrnc.net/blog/2014/11/how-to-install-a-magento-module - I believe this will be helpful.

Comment: Hey @LAW, i'm at step 4. `Run the modman script`, everything went well till this step, when i run `modman deploy-all` i get `modman: command not found`. All the other steps went oky, i can see the modman ...file i guess trough ftp

Comment: Is modman installed?